# How Can You Remove Grain from Photographs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I've took some photographs at a photoshoot last week. The lighting conditions weren't right for the shoot (my fault entirely) and the camera we used was a compact. Unfortunately this means that the photograph is quite grainy. Anyone know a good Photoshop (or similar) technique to improve this?

Comment: Could you rephrase the headline as a question?

Comment: @e100 - jeez your really cracking down on me ;)

Comment: This one should be moved to the photography site...

Comment: The question isn't really about "graphic design". It is better suited for the [Photo Stack Exchange](http://photo.stackexchange.com) site. Unfortunately, I cannot migrate it while the site is in beta so I suggest re-asking the question there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter > Noise > Reduce noise.

Reducing noise usually blurs the pixels making the image less sharp. play with the sliders to strike a good balance between sharpness and noise reduction

If the image is shot in RAW (unlikely on a compact) then Camera RAW v6 brought significant updates to the noise reduction engine. You'll get a better result [removing noise from the RAW](http://layersmagazine.com/overview-of-new-features-in-camera-raw-6.html) before you bring it into photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe push it in the other direction. Leverage the lo-fi-ness of it and further tweak the imagery in that direction?